# How to make the tableView look like the iPhone Settings Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How does the table view appear with rounded corners (as shown below)?

I would appreciate any sample code or may be some tutorial for having the table look rounded in the corners. Each section title also appears different from the conventional way..

[image]

Comment: You may find some answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview

Comment: First off, you will need a really big iPhone.

Comment: I would recommend github.com/beetlebugorg/RoundedUITableView as a good example !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a UITableViewStyleGrouped you can initialize it with:

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement datasource and delegate methods for UITableView and take Custom UITableView cell which has UITextField or add UITextField as sub view in cell's contentView