# issue with tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which has set the property `Grouped`.And it looks like this with rounded edges. And it's great.

[image]

As soon I start scrolling the `UITabelView` the round edges dissappear and it looks like this:

[image]

The round edges disappear!

How should I proceed that and when I scroll the `UITableView` up and down the round edges are kept as in the first picture?

The relevant code as asked:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [nameCatalog count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]];
    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *escapedString = [[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]      stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];


    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
    [webView setHidden:NO];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle:@"Retour" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(tableRetour:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = infoButton;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Does the UITableView slide under the text at the top?

Comment: No...the label containing the text is above the UITableView!!

Comment: The below link can solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview

Comment: if u want to show fully with round rect even while scrolling then make tableview as small to see enough in visible area.thats it

Comment: Ah. So the table slides below the text. Was dumb enough not to notice that :) I thought when you scroll up and come back your cells looks corrupted. As below answers say, that is how tables work. Maybe to hack around that you might need to figure out the cell that comes to top at the end of the scroll and redraw your table all over again. But I seriously don't understand why you want to do so. It would look abnormal as well. And by the way your UITableViewCell alloc initWithFrame is a deprecated method. You might want to do initWithStyle and then set the frame later.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in the first picture you are seeing the top row in the grouped tableView which is rounded, but only the top and bottom rows are rounded like that, so when you scroll you are seeing the middle rows which is normal.

Comment: Maybe is normal but I want the unormal then:)

Comment: in your mind, how would that go exaclty?! would the cells pop from being squared to being rounded edges?!

Comment: In my mind goes like this: I scroll up and down but the edge of the table is kept as in the first pic.Only the cells move.I tried with an imageview but the result wasn't as expected:)

Comment: You're going to have to do something custom to get the effect you want. Maybe start by having a look at the link to the github project mentioned below by sivakspt.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how grouped tables work. It's the corners of each group that are rounded, not the  corners of the table view itself. Take a look at the Settings app and you'll see that the corners of each group are rounded; you'll see essentially the same thing in Settings that you see in your app, except that the bounds of the table view in Settings correspond to the bounds of the scroll view. In short, your table view is working as designed.

If you want the corners of the visible part of the table to be rounded at all times, you could look into rounding the table view's corners. One way to do that is to set the `cornerRadius` property of the underlying layer:

```
myTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

If you try that approach, you'll probably also want to specify the layer's border width and color.

Answer (score 0):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-transparent-uiviews-rounded.html

https://github.com/beetlebugorg/RoundedUITableView

These link can help