# problem with the table view inside a scrollview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [issue with tableview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472573/issue-with-tableview-in-iphone)

I have the following:

.h file:

```
UITableView *catalogTable;
UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"BoiteAOutils");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    catalogTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    catalogTable.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
   [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    catalogTable.scrollEnabled = NO;
    catalogTable.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    [scrollView addSubview:catalogTable];


    nameCatalog = [myAudiAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].dataHandler.catalogueList;
    loadingView.hidden=YES;
}
```

I created a `scrollView` and a `tableView` in the `xib` file.
Everything works great and the result looks:

http://i53.tinypic.com/dzgqx3.png

I'm very haapy with the result, the problem is that as soon I start scrolling the table up and down it doesn't move.I can't see the whole content of the table...only the cells showed in this picture.
Where am I going wrong? Thank you:)

Answer (score 5):

You should never put a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`. Quoting the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) for a `UIScrollView`:

> **Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

You should rethink how you want your layout. Hope that Helps!