# How to replicate a UITableView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wanted to do a simple pagination inside a `UIScrollView` and within each page will have a TableView. For now, my first page always loaded with a `UITableView`, and how can I replicate it to another page too?

Is there any references link for this?

Comment: Is it `TableViewCell` or `TableView` ?

Comment: OOps,my bad, suppose to be TableView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481392/problem-with-the-table-view-inside-a-scrollview

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17678-best-practices-for-uitableview-within-uiview-within-uiscrollview.html

Comment: just go through this project.... https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

Comment: thanks for all the sources man!

Answer (score 2):

Check ATPagingView : https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS

I wanted to do exactly you seem to want to do, and ATPagingView helped me achieve it :)

Try the demo project, and in `DemoViewController` replace `self.pagingView.horizontal = NO;` by `self.pagingView.horizontal = YES;` to get horizontal paging instead of vertical paging

Hope this helps!