# Changing corner radius of the cells insie a grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After hours of googling I am wondering if it is possible to change the corner radius of a `grouped UITableView`.

I tried

> hoursTable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

but nothing seems to change.

Comment: You can check this out - http://programmingobsession.blogspot.in/2009/10/rounded-corners-on-uitableview.html

Comment: add [hoursTable setClipsToBounds:YES]; also to your code

Comment: let me know is it working or not

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but why are you setting the cornerRadius on the table but not the cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure clip sub views of table view alon with ur code
hoursTable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

by code **`[hoursTable setClipsToBounds:YES];`**

```
hoursTable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
[hoursTable setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't seem to work :( This is how it is. http://cl.ly/15253g0I373y3B3X0C2J

there is no change...it still looks like the default one.

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked, this changes the radius of the table view, not the table's cells. UITableViewStyleGrouped makes groups of cells with rounded corners. @Neelesh wants to change the radius of this, not the actual UITableView.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Question is about the `UITableViewCell` not the radius of the `UITableView`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure use `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework in your app

your method (`hoursTable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;` ) only  give you rounded corners without having to add your tableview to a superView or clipping it.

also use

```
[hoursTable setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

this is work only ios 3....if you work ios 4 or ios 5x then see [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview)

Comment: (hoursTable.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0; )  this work only ios 3x

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I am trying to change the corner curve on the first and the last cell alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10324/discussion-between-neelesh-and-elppa)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to

1) make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and set the background color clear

2) make a subclass of `UITableView` and set the separator color clear

3) use this cells in the tableview

now here is an important method t be implemented in `UITableViewCell` subclass

in 
`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method try to make a bezier path accordingly to fill and stroke path as far your corner radius and background color...

the content rect you can get by `self.contentView.frame` in what you have to draw your new bezier path.