# Custom rounded corners for first and last cell in a grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, rounded-corners, uitableview, cornerradius

My iPhone app is currently displaying a grouped table with 2 sections. I tried to change the radius of the rounded corners on the first and last cells of each section (or on the same cell in the case of sections with just one row) using:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

or acting on the whole tableview:

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

but no luck...Of course I've imported *QuartzCore* before performing this operation. It looks like it's possible to customise the corners only when the table is displayed with plain style.

The ideal solution would be to customise top corners in the first one and bottom corners in the last.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The grouped table Corners of each group are rounded rite?

Comment: i had come across same problem... and i dont think grouped table are much effective when you want to edit its shapes

Comment: Take a look at this; might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview

Comment: Doesn't grouped `tableView` has rounded corner itself ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is:

1. Make a custom cells in a xib file, set their unique identifiers like: `@"beginCell", @"middleCell", @"endCell"`. You can make it according to this tutorial: http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/
2. In method 
   `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
   you have to find ejther you are in the middle or on begin/end of the section and use the cell with proper identifier.

Comment: You can also perform custom cell drawing as you did before, but do it in the tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Again you will need separate identifiers for middle and begin/end cells.

Answer (score 18):

Here's what works in Swift 4.2 and I think also works in Swift 5 (but haven't tried).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cornerRadius = 5
    var corners: UIRectCorner = []

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        corners.update(with: .topLeft)
        corners.update(with: .topRight)
    }

    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
    {
        corners.update(with: .bottomLeft)
        corners.update(with: .bottomRight)
    }

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds,
                                  byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                  cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius)).cgPath
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Please leave a comment if this works in Swift 5.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/410-core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-and-contexts#toc-anchor-003 : "Note: Drawing static views with Core Graphics is generally quick enough, but if your views move around or need frequent redrawing, you should use Core Animation layers. Core Animation is optimized so that the GPU, not the CPU, handles most of the processing. In contrast, the CPU processes view drawing performed by Core Graphics in draw(_:)"

Comment: @rs7 Seems this makes things more complicated and don't think there's a need performance-wise. But, please post your answer and ping me; I'd love to see how this turns out.

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Comment: top right and bottom right is not applying

Comment: @Ryan110 Why are `topRight` and `bottomRight` not applicable?

Answer (score 3):

I subclass my tableview cells:

```
class CGStandardCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    func setCornerRadius(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, inTableView tableView: UITableView) {
        let lastRow = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
        self.layer.maskedCorners = []

        if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == lastRow {
            self.cornerRadius = 20
            self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner,
                                        .layerMinXMinYCorner,
                                        .layerMinXMaxYCorner,
                                        .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.cornerRadius = 20
            self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner,
                                        .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        } else if indexPath.row == lastRow {
            self.cornerRadius = 20
            self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner,
                                        .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

```
cell.setCornerRadius(forIndexPath: indexPath, inTableView: tableView)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add a `UIView` on the background of a cell, make the cell background as clearcolor . Adjust the `UIView` to have rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView  *view = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:YourFrame];
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

cell.backgroundView = view;
```

And don't forget the `UITableView` background color to be transparent.

Comment: this is ok if there is only one row. But with multiple rows the only rounded corners to be modified should be the top ones for the first and the bottom ones for the last. I think this approach affects also all the corners between the cells.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
        UIView  *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.backgroundView = view;
        //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    
    
}

Answer (score 1):

If You need just rounded corners there's another solution (inspired by grouped style of native uitableview(cell), in slowmo :) ). It should be something like this:

Cell subclass...

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic) top;
@property (nonatomic) bottom;
@end

@implementation MyCell
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // remove white default background
        //example settings, UIImageViews with resizable images can be used too
        self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.selectedBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5; // 
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.backgroundView.frame = self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.top?0:-self.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius, 0, self.bottom?0:-self.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius, 0));
}
-(void)setTop:(BOOL)top{
    _top = top;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
-(void)setBottom:(BOOL)bottom{
    _bottom = bottom;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
@end
```

In dataSource you can just do this:...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      ...cell initialization stuff...
      [(MyCell *)cell setTop:(indexPath.row == 0)];
      [(MyCell *)cell setBottom:(indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)];

      return cell;
}
```

Pros:

- one background for all cells
- easy to use
- animateable (You're changing positions instead of images)
- can be used for plain style as well (but watchout for sections :) )

Cons:

- subclass for cell is needed (I couldn't find a way to adjust backgrounds positions even after change of rowHeight)
- doesn't solve my problem with rounded corners of whole section (You have to round corners for section view manualy)

I hope this helps someone, but be aware that this code is not tested! I've implemented this idea few minutes before posting this answer and it just seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

For storyboards, in iOS >= 13.0

Set UITableView style to `Inset Grouped`

[image: Storyboard menu drop down]

Comment: This is good for tableview cells (whatever you write in `cellForRow` method). If you have Header (`viewForHeaderInSection` method)  then this isn't good.