# Making rounded corners for the first and last cell of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to make rounded corners for the first and last cell of UITableView. I have seen from this post[Custom Rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492200/custom-rounded-corners-for-first-and-last-cell-in-a-grouped-uitableview) that you can use custom cells in a xib file, set their unique identifiers like: @"beginCell", @"middleCell", @"endCell". I do not want to use custom cells. Is there any other way to do this?

For example:

```
if (cell.count == 0 or cell.count == last)
{
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}
```

Something like this. But there is no property called count. Is there any other property?

**EDITED:**

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableItems,images;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item1",@"Item2",@"Item3",nil];
    images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"target.png"],nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark - Required Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tableItems.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Step 1:Check whether if we can reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //If there are no new cells to reuse,create a new one
    if(cell ==  nil)
    { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
        //changing the radius of the corners
        //cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    }

    //Set the image in the row
    cell.imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 3: Set the cell text content
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 4: Return the row
    return cell;

}
#pragma mark - Optional Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSString *selectedRow = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    secondViewController.selectedRow = selectedRow;

    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [secondViewController printRowNumber:indexPath.row];
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your `UITableView` initialization style to Grouped like that:

```
yourTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

This will make your first cell rounded from top and last cell rounded from bottom.

**EDIT in case of not using UITableViewController initializer:**

```
@interface YourViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

@end


@implementation YourViewController

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        ...
        tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        ...
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: what if you are not using UITableViewController?

Comment: what if you are using  single view application?

Comment: The init your `tableView` with `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style`

Comment: tried this: - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    return self;
}
but compiler is giving me error....

Comment: Seems you are subclassing UITableView. You can use `initWithFrame:style:` instead of `initWithStyle` inside your designated initializer of your custom class e.g. `[super initWithFrame:frame style:style];`. Or just don't implement this initializer and use the one from base class, since you don't do anything special in there.

Comment: `UITableViewController` doesn't have `initWithFrame` initializer, you should initialize `tableView` with given style and not `tableViewController`. e.g if you want to have initWithFrame initializer for viewController you can leave it but don't call initWithFrame on super but on your tableView property.

Comment: when i add this line: [self.view addSubView:tableView];
the compiler gives me this error: No visible @interface for ViewController declares the selector 'addSubView:'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're putting this code in `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you can do it like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == ([indexPath length]-1))
{
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your usage of indexPath.length ... from this code someone could asume, that length of indexPath is number of rows in section, BUT length is number of indexes and indexPath ALWAYS has 2 indexes (section and row). So indexPath.length is always equal 2!