# Hiding the first row using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uitableview

Please help me out. I have a simple Core Data model with an ManagedObject called Turn, with a NSDate value updatedAt and with a property called "gameId"
In a UITableView in my app, I want to show all Turns with a specific gameId, except the most recent Turn. Constructing the NSFetchedResultsController is really tough, because I cannot put a simple predicate in it. Setting fetchOffset to 1 does not work, since NSFetchedResultsController does not bother about this.
Also, just reducing numberOfRowsInSection by 1 gives quite a lot of problems, because NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate has a lot of checks built in, and throws errors.

What is a simple solution to this problem?

Can anybody help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just hide it with something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 80;
 }
```

Comment: That seems like a great solution, Edwin! Thanks a lot! It is indeed a simple solution :) And what should I do with cellForRowAtIndexPath? Return a cell with a frame height of zero?

Comment: That doesn't matter, you can return whatever you like. You could just return a new UITableViewCell or the cell as all the other cells. It won't be displayed anyway.

Comment: Well, I've tested it and the first cell is still displayed. Since I have constructed the layout of the cell in the Storyboard, it seems to overrule the empty row height setting. Will try to return a plain UITableViewCell like you said.

Comment: Clip to bounds is probably turned off.

Comment: You just made my day. And it could be even better if you would also know a solution to get rounded corners on top of the first cell that is appearing know :)  (UITableViewStyle is grouped).

Comment: Do you want the entire tableview to have rounded corners? then you could use something like myTableView.layer.cornerRadius=5; For more options see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview

Comment: Thanks Edwin! I found a solution for it there. I'm out of questions ;) - geintje natuurlijk