# iOS custom buttons and scroll view like venmo

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, uiscrollview

How do you create buttons like the "Settings", "Notifications", and "Cash Out" buttons in venmo shown below? Also, is the scroll view they use just a `UIScrollView` or a modified `UITableView`? I can't figure out how to add things like the buttons or the picture with balance info and name to a `UITableView`.

[image]

Comment: Most likely a plain table view in grouped style. Seems rather straightforward. I would recommend you to run through a bunch of tutorials regarding UITableView and also to check its specifications thoroughly. Make sure you understand the concept of cell-reuse and how to build custom cells. Its all in there!

Answer (score 4):

1. For this example, I think it's easier to use a `UITableView` than to build a custom subclass of `UIScrollView`. If you want to customize the look of the table view's cells, initialize the table view with the `UITableViewStylePlain` style and give each `UITableViewCell` the appropriate `backgroundView` & `selectedBackgroundView` in `–[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`.
2. For the "Settings," "Notifications," and "Cash Out" buttons, just add them as subviews of the cell in the first row of the first section. Use `-[UIButton setTitle:forState:]` & `-[UIButton setImage:forState:]` to give each button a title & image, respectively. Set the `UIButton` properties `titleEdgeInsets` and/or `imageEdgeInsets` so that each button's title appears below its image.
3. To add a picture with a name, bio, and balance at the top, use the `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView`. In `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]`, initialize a `UIView *tableHeaderView` with the desired height and give it subviews, e.g., `pictureButton`, `nameLabel`, `bioTextView`, `balanceLabel`. Then, do `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView`.

Answer (score 1):

They have used tableView. It contains 3 sections. They have chaged customCell in each section. In cellForRow delegate method you get section. Accordingly you can change cells. In CustomCell you can add any view like buttons.

Comment: What about the top part that is not in a cell?

Comment: ^yea but I think I figured out that it's just a tableView header instead of a section header

Comment: Do you know how to adjust the cornerRadius of the groups too?

Comment: try http://www.hanspinckaers.com/reproducing-a-tableview-like-in-stocks-spotlight-weather also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview